# Can you bind the Windows "Server" service to an ip/interface?

Tags: security, network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm running `Windows Server 2008 R2`.  I would like to bind the `Server` service which listens on port `445` to a specific ip address or interface.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want/need to do that?  What actual problem are you facing?

Comment: i've got multiple nics/subnets and i don't want the service exposed to all of them.  it's a basic security measure.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with trying to change how the service binds (which I don't think you can do), perhaps just use the built-in Windows 2008 firewall instead.

Create a new incoming rule for that port with a narrow [scope](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771905.aspx) to allow that traffic only if it comes in on a specific IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install RPCCfg. This can be downloaded from TechNet on the Microsoft web site

Run rpccfg –q

C:\Program Files\Resource Kit>rpccfg -q
RPCCFG: Listening on all interfaces (default configuration)

RPCCFG: Using default port settings

This tells us that we are listening on all interfaces and using default ports. Now we get a list of all the adapters, so run rpccfg –l

C:\Program Files\Resource Kit>rpccfg -l
IF[65540]: Ethernet: HP NC371i Multifunction Gigabit Server Adapter
IF[65539]: Ethernet: HP NC371i Multifunction Gigabit Server Adapter #2
IF[1]: Ethernet: MS TCP Loopback interface

Now we need to modify what interfaces RPC listens to. So in this instance, the first interface is our internal, and the second interface (#2) is our external, so we want to disable RPC on the second interface. So we run rpccfg –a 1 65540
This makes RPC listen on the Loopback interface and the internal interface.

C:\Program Files\Resource Kit>rpccfg -a 1 65540
RPCCFG: Listening on the following interfaces
IF[1]: Ethernet: MS TCP Loopback interface
IF[65540]: Ethernet: HP NC371i Multifunction Gigabit Server Adapter

You can now verify the config of RPC:

C:\Program Files\Resource Kit>rpccfg -q
RPCCFG: Listening on the following interfaces
IF[1]: Ethernet: MS TCP Loopback interface
IF[65540]: Ethernet: HP NC371i Multifunction Gigabit Server Adapter

RPCCFG: Using default port settings

Comment: As of Windows 7 and Windows 8, if I use rpccfg to limit the ip addresses used (either to the loopback interface or a specific NIC), the system becomes unstable and either crashes or fails to allow me to login.  This issue has been reported here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/eb294fc0-7454-486f-a0a2-788397fda242/win7pro-using-netsh-rpc-add-127001-or-rpccfg-a-1-causes-rpc-subsystem-to-crash?forum=w7itprosecurity and I haven't seen it addressed anywhere.